# typescript - disable Event type in @types/node

Tags: typescript

There's an `Event` type in `dom-events.d.ts` in the `@types/node` package that conflicts with an `Event` type I have in my local codebase.  I want to remove this type (and preferably everything in `dom-events.d.ts`, since it makes no sense for them to exist when I'm making a node process that doesn't have a DOM).

Comment: The best solution would be not to name your own classes the same as standard types. But generally speaking, unless you're importing them both, they generally get resolved in the imports. What's the concrete code that fails with that?

Comment: renaming my own class isn't a solution, it's a hacky workaround that i want to avoid.  I'm not importing @types/node's Event, it's implicitely included by typescript.  And since it's included automatically, I'm never prompted to import my own class, so I need to manually do it every time, and if I ever miss a case I get weird hard to track down bugs